# Value of $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x^2}\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x^2})\right)^2dx$

Tags: calculus

I need to find the value of this integral : $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x^2}\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x^2})\right)^2dx$ .

I tried to integrate by parts $\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x^2}\left(\frac{d^{n+1}}{dx^{n+1}}(e^{-x^2})\right)^2dx$  but I'm stuck for the expression of the antiderivative. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

(n is a positive integer)

Comment: Have you tried brute force - taking the derivative (which will be a polynomial times $e^{-x^2}$)  After squaring the integrand will be another polynomial times $e^{-x^2}$, which can be integrated explicitly.

Comment: What is the value of $n$, or are you trying to get a general expression for all values of $n$?

Comment: @JohnOmielan n is a positive integer, so I'm trying to get a general expression

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x^2}\left(\frac{d^n}{dx^n}(e^{-x^2})\right)^2dx=
(\frac{d^n}{dy^n}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{x^2}e^{-(x+y)^2}e^{-(x+z)^2}dx)|_{y=0,z=0}$ $=(\frac{d^n}{dy^n}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\int\limits_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-(x+y+z)^2}e^{2yz}dx)|_{y=0,z=0}$
$=(\frac{d^n}{dy^n}\frac{d^n}{dz^n}\sqrt{\pi}e^{2yz})|_{y=0,z=0}=2^n n!\sqrt{\pi}$
(modulo mistakes that you will easily repair)

Comment: @MariuszIwaniuk you are right  - aparently I don't know how to differentiate $\exp$ :)